# NodeJS Swig math

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm completely baffled by swig templating in node. How do I subtract two values?

Neither of the following works:

```
{{ stop - start }}
{{ stop|add(-start) }}
```

I ended up having to compute this in the view and pass it in. Is that the only way? I guess I could write my own `subtract` filter, but that seems like a bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you'll have to write a custom filter.

In the next version of Swig, which is undergoing a full rewrite, you'll be able to use [simple operators in variables](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/bd3f5a0dc08078ffd4372fa61248f8d50d8cbbf8/tests/variables.test.js#L17-24).

Comment: Any updates on this? I can't tell from the source code :/